# Onclick Event formatting in React App Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Can anyone help with the following error?

I know that there is a problem with the Typescript type, so I am reaching out to the experts!

```
  Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>' is not assignable to type 'MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>'.
      Types of property 'currentTarget' are incompatible.
        Type 'EventTarget & HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'EventTarget & HTMLButtonElement'.
          Type 'EventTarget & HTMLElement' is missing the following properties from type 'HTMLButtonElement': disabled, form, formAction, formEnctype, and 13 more.  TS2322

    160 |                   variant="outline-secondary"
    161 |                   className="search-button"
  > 162 |                   onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) =>
        |                   ^
    163 |                     this.onSearch(event)
    164 |                   }
    165 |                 >
^C
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but doesn't the error literally tell you what's wrong? You've typed it as `HTMLButtonElement` in your code, and the error says its `HTMLElement` instead.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal, reproducible code

Comment: Yes already tried that, the error just shifts to the event in this.onSearch, saying that the properties are still missing.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot find out which sort of element you're adding this onClick if it is a button so do it like this.
Change event type to React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>;

Hopefully, it will solve your problem.

```
      onClick={(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) =>               
                  this.onSearch(event)
     }
```